# Powerpoint: applescript command to paste with "keep source formatting"

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

Basically, I'm writing a script to accomplish a few things: save selected files as a new presentation with "Keep Source Formatting", and then do a Save As... so that it prompts me where to save the file. Seems pretty straightforward, but it's not. Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? I'm surprised it's so convoluted.

My script so far:

**tell** application “Microsoft PowerPoint”
  **activate**
  **copy** object slide range of selection of active window
  **set** newPresentation to make new presentation
  **paste** object newPresentation
  **save** newPresentation
**end** **tell**

This does not allow me to "Keep Source Formatting", and it saves it using the headline as the filename into the user library. I need the save as dialog to save it properly.

Comment: I cannot test this right now but try
`paste and format (text object of selection) type format surrounding formatting with emphasis`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried dozens of ways but nothing seems to want to work.